# Unity3D is sizing icons differently

Tags: unity-game-engine

Bellow is a section of my games UI made in Unity3D. I was adding the icon on the left side when I realized that it was much larger than the icon in the middle so I went to give them a similar size. According to the `Rect Transform` of these objects the icon in the center of the screen is larger than the one on the left which again according to the `Rect Transform` is the smallest icon on the screen.

[image]

Does anyone know of why this might be? I don't quite understand Unity's units of measure.  These icons are nested in many game objects with Layout Groups, Content Size Fitters, and Layout Elements. So I am not exactly sure what is retentive to these icons but I will show their parents and grand parents here.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

If There is anything else I can you would need to know I can post more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the scale of the rect transforms so I assume they are the same.
Layout groups and content size fitters will (if you allow them to) change the size of the GameObject to make it fit a certain space, that is what they are for! This will then override the size that you have manually given to the GameObjects.

Comment: Yes, you are correct the scale of all four of these objects are set to XYZ=1.

Comment: Oh my goodness... the most great grand parent game object had a scale of 3. I do not remember setting that at all. it makes no sense as I never scale my objects. I always have the layout components control the size of things.

Comment: Glad it worked out!